# How to find out if offset cursor is at EOF with lseek()?

Tags: c, eof, libc, lseek

How can I find out if the offset cursor is currently at EOF by using `lseek()` only?

Comment: Why do you want to do that? The closest I can think of is calling it twice and compare the return values `if(lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_CUR) == lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END))`, which also sets the file position to the end. "Currently at `EOF`" is a little unclear, the EOF condition is set after an attempt to read past the last byte, not if the file position is at the end.

Comment: @mafso: I'd say what you call "*closest*" is the comapct version of the correct answer. So why not make it an answer?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`lseek`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/lseek.html) returns the (new) position. If it's acceptable that the file position is at the end after the test, the following works:

```
off_t old_position = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_CUR);
off_t end_position = lseek(fd, 0, SEEK_END);
if(old_position == end_position) {
    /* cursor already has been at the end */
}
```

Now, the cursor is at the end, whether it already has been there or not; to set it back, you can do `lseek(fd, old_position, SEEK_SET)` afterwards.

(I omitted checks for errors (return value of `(off_t)-1`) for sake of shortness, remember to include them in the real code.)

An alternative, though using another function, would be to query the current position as above and `fstat` the file to see if the `st_size` field equals the current position.

As a note, the end-of-file condition is set for streams (`FILE *`, not the `int` file descriptors) after an attempt to read past the end of the file, the cursor being at the end is not enough (that is, this approach is not the file descriptor equivalent to `feof(stream)`).

Comment: Won't the `st_size` field giving the file size be *equal* to the `SEEK_END` position? (As with an array, one past the max index is the size). `SEEK_END` sets to the next position for writing, not to the last byte.